# Spell My Username in the Following Code No. 2

Tags: cipher

I have developed a code, this time **purely a conversion from letters to numbers**. I have put a table below with 3 words or phrases and their corresponding codes. Your job is to write my username in the code (a space is still a space in the code, and this is not case-sensitive).

| Word/Phrase | Code |
| --- | --- |
| absolutely | 1406430645 |
| chocolate | 395462305 |
| very smart | 22705 203300 |

**Bonus Question:** Once you figured out how the code works and how to encode any word, can you figure out a method to decode any word?

---

Other puzzles in the series: [No. 1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118001/spell-my-username-in-the-following-code-no-1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cheese Cake is:

> 385695 3215
>  (Assuming the same encoding for upper and lower case letters)

Because:

> The encoding is a positional sum of the A1Z26 encoding of the individual letters.
>
>  E.g. For absolutely we have:
>
> ```
>  a    1
>  b +   2
>  s +   19
>  o +    15
>  l +     12
>  u +      21
>  t +       20
>  e +         5
>  l +         12
>  y +          25
>  ----------------
>       1406430645
> ```

And for the bonus question:

> No it is not possible to unambiguously decode any word, because multiple words can encode to the same number.
>  E.g. "He" and "go" both encode to 85. And so would "fy" if it were a valid word.
>  And as you add more letters/digits, the number of options increases.

Comment: Nice, you got the correct answer! +1